# Rebinding C-S-s?

Tags: key-bindings

I'm trying to set up `C-S-s` to run `isearch-forward-symbol-at-point`, but when I do the obvious step of:

```
(global-set-key [C-S-s] 'isearch-forward-symbol-at-point)
```

It doesn't work.  It just does a normal incremental search.  When I press `C-h k`, followed by `C-S-s` (to find out what it's actually doing) emacs tells me:

```
C-s (**translated from C-S-s**) runs the command isearch-forward (found in
global-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
‘isearch.el’.
```

**I *think* my question is "How do I stop C-S-s from being translated so that I can rebind that key sequence to `isearch-forward-symbol-at-point`?"**

(I read up on keymaps and translation a bit, but it's not clear to me which translation keymap I should be changing, or how to change it)(maybe local-/global-unset-key?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually the problem is not the translation: if you had bound the key that you meant to bind, it would have precedence over the translation. The problem is that you didn't bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

There are several syntaxes for keyboard events and it can occasionally get confusing. You can use modifier prefixes like `C-` for Control and `S-` for Shift with [function keys](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Keys.html#Function-Keys), but not with characters. Your binding is for a function key whose name is `C-S-s`, and has no practical effect since there is no such key on your keyboard. For a character, even with modifiers, you need to use a character literal.

```
(global-set-key [?\C-\S-s] 'isearch-forward-symbol-at-point)
```

Some modifier+character combinations can be expressed with a [string](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Nonprinting-Characters.html#Nonprinting-Characters) instead of an array of characters, e.g. `(global-set-key "\C-s" 'isearch-forward)`. But strings can only store characters with modifiers that result in another string character: the result has to be an [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character, or Meta plus an ASCII character, or a member of an extended character set such as Unicode. Other modifier combinations can be expressed through [character constants](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Character-Type.html#Character-Type), but these characters can't be put in strings.

Instead of using a character literal, you can [build the key chord using a list](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Changing-Key-Bindings.html#Changing-Key-Bindings) containing the modifiers and, at the end, the base key.

```
(global-set-key [(control shift ?s)] 'isearch-forward-symbol-at-point)
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`kbd` macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Sequences.html#index-kbd-1797) and let it build the key sequence from the usual user-visible syntax. It will figure out that `C-S-s` means a modified character S and not a function key.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-s") 'isearch-forward-symbol-at-point)
```

Comment: @MikeTheTall, personally I strongly recommend the `(kbd "C-S-s")` syntax and using `kbd` in general, as that way you can use the description of the key sequence that Emacs gives you, verbatim, which tends to eliminate confusion.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks!
(And, for the future, I will just default to the `(kbd)` syntax!)